# как настроить 301 редирект ко страницы .html на страницу wordpress со слэшем на конце

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Прошу прощения за свою тупость, но никак не получается настроить редирект 301 со статического сайта на сайт вордпресс

Исходная страница http://site1.com/page1.html 
Страница редиректа: http://site2.com/2018/01/page2/

Если прописываю, как для обыкновенных страниц .html - выдает "Страница не найдена"

Спасибо

Comment: Где и что вы прописываете?

Comment: в файле .htaccess я прописываю Redirect 301 /page1.html http://newsite.ru/page2.html  - это работает нормально. НО, если я пишу Redirect 301 /page1.html http://newsite.ru/page2/  при редиректе выдает, что Страница не найдена

Comment: Т.е., у меня не получается сделать редирект 301 на страницу вордпресс, адрес которой заканчивается не на .html, а одним слэшем  /

Comment: лучше покажите содержимое `htaccess` на 1 и 2 сайте.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Вопрос решен.Проблема заключалась в кириллице, которая присутствует в адресной строке вордпресс, она некорректно обрабатывалась. Надо было все это делать в кодировке KOI-8